# Can an analyzer be made that will auto indent preprocessor directives?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, roslyn-code-analysis

I like to indent the code in my `#region` blocks for readability (personal preference). However the default behavior of the Text Editor is to inline code with its surrounding region, as follows:

```
#region

// code defaults to this position 

#endregion
```

I have not been able to find any extensions that will allow the following indentation behavior:

```
#region

    // code should indent to here by default

#endregion
```

Can roslyn code analysis be used to write an analyzer which enforced this formatting?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah you could definitely do that. If you put your above code into a C# file and look at the Syntax Visualizer (View -> Other Windows) you will see that the the `#region` is viewed as a `RegionDirectiveTrivia` instance with the comment being a `SingleLineCommentTrivia`.
[image]

It looks like you would just need to create a longer `WhitespaceTrivia` before the `SingleLineCommentTrivia`